Safe-Multisig shows contract calls as fallback, despite using the UI transaction builder
We are using the transaction builder to setup a contract call to a proxy. During this phase, the UI correctly detects the ABI of the implementation contract, and we use it to build the calldata.
However, once the batch of transactions is added to the queue, the detailed view shows the call as fallback, and does not even show the data payload. This makes it extremely hard for other signers to verify what's going on with the proposed transaction. I think it used to work correctly other times, so I do not understand what may have changed now.

Thank you for taking the time to write this feedback. It has been forwarded to the corresponding team. I cannot give you an estimate of when/if this will be implemented, but I will notify you here of any updates on this matter.
Thank you again for pointing this out 
Best, Louis
